# iPhone - Splitting an NSString into char NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I've got a 2d NSArray of  {{"foo","food only only"}, {"bar","babies are rad"} ... } and I need to end up with 2 NSArrays: one of characters and one of the corresponding words. So @"f", @"o",@"b",@"a",@"r"  and @"food",@"only",@"babies",@"are",@"rad" would be my two NSArray's of NSStrings.

So first, how do I get @"f",@"o",@"o" from @"foo"

And second how can I only keep the uniques? I'm guessing NSDictionary and only add if key is not there giving me @"f":@"food" @"o":@"only"  then use getObjects:andKeys: to get two C arrays which I'll convert to NSArrays..

Based on the below answer I went with the following. I didn't actually use the NSMutableDict, I just added my letters to it to get the uniqueness check before creating my 2 output arrays:

```
        unichar ch = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCharacters: &ch length: 1];

        if (![dict objectForKey:s]) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the individual characters of a string, try `-characterAtIndex:`. That will get you them as the `unichar` primitive type, which you can then wrap in `NSString` like so:

```
unichar ch = ...;
NSString *chString = [NSString stringWithCharacters: &ch length: 1];
```

To keep uniques, you can store objects in an `NSMutableSet`, though it will not preserve the order in which objects are added to it.

Comment: Would adding two NSArrays of {@"f", @"foo"} and {@"f",@"foo"} to a mutableset end up with both added or would they test as equal and only one would be added?

Comment: The union set of the sets `{ f, foo }` and `{ f, foo }` is `{ f, foo }`. Equal objects appear only once no matter how many times you add them.

Answer (score 1):

getCharacters will get you started with an array of characters: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCharacters:

You could cycle through and check for uniques after